# $L/K$ field extension and $[M : K] ≤ C$ holds for all real intermediate fields $M$. Then $[L : K]$ is also finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, extension-field

I want to check my solution for this exercise:

Let $L/K$ be a field extension and there exists a constant $C ∈ \mathbb{N}$ such that $[M : K] ≤ C$ holds for all proper intermediate fields $M$. Then $[L : K]$ is also finite.

To prove this can I not simply do this?:

$L=\cup_{i=0}^n M_i$ for $K\subset M_i \subset L$ $\Rightarrow [L:K]\leq C^n\Rightarrow$ $[L:K]$ is finite.

Comment: No, this can’t work. The easiest counter-example is that of finite extensions with infinitely many intermediate subfields – so you’d need infinitely many $M_i$. Also, the $M_i$ cannot be disjoint since they all contain $K$, and you didn’t prove you could consider finitely many of them. Finally, you should clarify what you meant by “real intermediate”. Do you mean fields that are proper subfields of $L$ and contain $K$?

Comment: Yes I mean  proper subfields of L and contain K @Aphelli

Comment: How can I prove that there are finitely many $M_i$? @Aphelli

Comment: You can’t. There are finite extensions with infinitely many intermediate subfields.

Comment: so how can I solve this problem @Aphelli ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $L$ is algebraic over $K$: were an element $t \in L \setminus K$ transcendental, then $K\subsetneq K(t^2)$ would be a proper infinite subextension.

The poset of proper intermediate fields (wrt inclusion) can be empty only when $L/K$ [is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120383/is-there-an-extension-field-of-degree-infinite-has-no-intermediate-field), so we can consider the nonempty case. By problem statement the poset has finite height, so we can find a maximal element $L/F/K$. Take $\alpha \in L \setminus F$. Then the compositum $F(\alpha)$ is equal to $L$, and it has $K$-dimension at most $[F:K] [K(\alpha):K] \le C^2$.

**Exercise:** find a tower $L/F/K$ that attains the equality.